# Deserializing JSON into user-defined case classes with Jerkson

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jerkson

I came across this excellent [tutorial](http://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/processing-json-in-scala-with-jerkson/) on processing JSON in Scala using Jerkson. In particular, I am interested in deserializing JSON into user-defined case classes. The article has a simple example

```
case class Simple(val foo: String, val bar: List[String], val baz: Map[String,Int])

object SimpleExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._
    val simpleJson = """{"foo":42, "bar":["a","b","c"], "baz":{"x":1,"y":2}}"""
    val simpleObject = parse[Simple](simpleJson)
    println(simpleObject)
  }
}
```

I got this error running it, I am on Play 2.0.1, Scala 2.9.1-1, Jerkson 0.5.0.

```
Execution exception [[ParsingException: Unable to find a case accessor
```

Also found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/MKNPYOj9LBA/Ll6Fch98ZBkJ) on Google Groups but it isn't helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it change anything if you remove the redundant "val" declarations from the case class fields (they're not necessary for case classes)?

Comment: Of course you're not trying this on the REPL?

Comment: @pagoda_5b nope, it's in the Play app, so the syntax is a bit different than above because I don't need `main`.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I don't know Jerkson, but Spray-Json makes this type of stuff easy. The example below is from the [Spray-Json readme](https://github.com/spray/spray-json):

```
 case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

val json = Color("CadetBlue", 95, 158, 160).toJson
val color = json.convertTo[Color]
```

Here's a slightly different example from [someone's git repository](https://github.com/jestan/spray-json-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/cc/spray/json/example/SprayJsonExamples.scala):

```
package cc.spray.json.example

import cc.spray.json._


object EnumSex extends Enumeration {
  type Sex = Value
  val MALE = Value("MALE")
  val FEMALE = Value("FEMALE")
}

case class Address(no: String, street: String, city: String)

case class Person(name: String, age: Int, sex: EnumSex.Sex, address: Address)

object SprayJsonExamples {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val json = """{ "no": "A1", "street" : "Main Street", "city" : "Colombo" }"""
    val address = JsonParser(json).fromJson[Address]
    println(address)

    val json2 = """{ "name" : "John", "age" : 26, "sex" : 0 , "address" : { "no": "A1", "street" : "Main Street", "city" : "Colombo" }}"""

    val person = JsonParser(json2).fromJson[Person]
    println(person)
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll look into that for future apps but unfortunately, I need to use Jerkson.

Comment: Cool, apologies for not being able to help you out with Jerkson.